# XML-XSD: Element 'choice' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Estoy intentando validar mi xml con el schema pero me da un error que no consigo corregir.

El error que sale cuando valido es "s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_person' is invalid. Element 'choice' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often."

Este sería mi xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<persons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/home/familia.xsd">
<person>
    <full_name>Hege Refsnes</full_name>
    <child_name>Cecilie</child_name>
</person>
<person>
    <full_name>Tove Refsnes</full_name>
    <child_name>Hege</child_name>
    <child_name>Stale</child_name>
    <child_name>Jim</child_name>
    <child_name>Borge</child_name>
</person>
<person>
    <full_name>Stale Refsnes</full_name>
    <child_name>Android</child_name>
</person>
</persons>
```

Y aqui el XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="persons">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="person" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="full_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema de poner la etiqueta al nivel correcto, en tu caso tu `xs:choice` tiene que ir dentro del `xs:sequence`, es decir:

```
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="full_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Ni me había dado cuenta. Muchas gracias